# Simple Razor C# .Net form: Checkboxes and Session Variable settings

Tags: c#, .net, session, razor, checkbox

First, I want to explain I do not know any Razor or C#. I have a client that I build out high-fidelity prototyping for. Some of the elements are getting kind of advanced where JavaScript is not working for me anymore.

The Ask:

I have a modal that I trigger (using bootstrap), this modal has some checkboxes in a form. Each checkbox will trigger to turn on or turn off a session that will turn certain elements on or off on a series of 5-6 pages. Here I am just working with one of those sessions. I can duplicate once I figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
@{

if (Request.Form["fitscorechecked"] != null && Request.Form["fitscorechecked"] == "on") {
    Session["fitscore"] = "on";

} else {
    Session["fitscore"] = "off";
}
}
```

My Form:

```
    <form method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 bottom5"><input type="checkbox" id="fitscorechecked" name="fitscorechecked" value="true"/> &nbsp;&nbsp; Show fit score during adjustment</div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 bottom5"><input type="checkbox" id="Anonymous" name="Anonymous" value="true" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; Make contributors anonymous</div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 bottom5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<h5>Advanced Options</h5><h6>Will allow you to view related tasks, manually adjust patterns (power users only), and the ability to download responses.</h6>">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Advanced" name="Advanced" value="true" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; Show advanced options</div>
            </div>
            <div class="prototype-btngroup-center">
               <a class="btn btn-default prototype-btn-spacersm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
               <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" href="#stepAlign6" data-toggle="tab" data-step="5" data-dismiss="modal">Begin Alignment</a>
            </div>  
            </form> 
<form>
```

I have never built a form in .net so I am really lost. I just need something very simple that does not use controllers. Much of this code is show and then redone based on the updates from the product team, so something that is simple and easy to adjust.

Comment: What backend technology are you using?  Classic ASP, WebForms, Mvc, or Web Pages?

Comment: You've kind of explained what you're looking to do (sort of), but you haven't explained what the problem is.  What isn't working?  In what way is it not working?  What are you asking?  If the question is "I don't know ASP.NET, please teach me" then I'm afraid that's not really what we do here.  There are tutorials to get you started.

Comment: I wouldn't get rid of the controllers, rather I'd create a model of three boolean values and let MVC do the binding for you automatically.  That was you don't have to drop to the request layer to parse the content.   This is called strongly typed binding in MVC.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly

Comment: I am using MVC, but I really only code in HTML, CSS and JavaScript/JQuery. The code above is not setting the session. I just need help with this one thing and that will fix everything I need to know to finish this project, I did lots of reading and couldn't find sample code that could address myissue... I don't really need to learn .net as that is not what I am programming, I just have this one need. John I will research that and see what I can come up with.